# How replace prefix "WebResource_" in name new web resources in crm dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Where can I change this setting to replace prefix "WebResource_"  with my own prefix?

[image: webpage screenshot]

Comment: It’s by design.

Comment: was my answer helpful? could you please mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the Web Resource itself will take on a prefix that is defined in your publisher settings:
[image]

I do not think you can edit the name of the web resource prefix when you add it to the form, because it is telling the form on the back end that it needs to access a Web Resource. What is the business case for changing it?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change that. That is defined from dynamics (Microsoft) to identify it is a web resource component. 
What you could do is change the JavaScript (webresource) prefix like in place of bydefualt "new" to something you like. This can be done creating your publisher

[Creating publisher and prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/change-solution-publisher-prefix)